# Laravel: Count number of uploads and return those

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Using [this](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1270) lib uploading works great. I have number of objects in an excel and I go through them and do whatever I desire.

The question is while uploading the excel I am ought to check whether a particular object already exists, if so increment the `$rejected` variable otherwise create and increment the `$uploaded` variable. As a result I would like to return the results: how many uploaded and how many rejected? Whats the best way to do as such? It is obvious I can't access those variables inside the function. What's the best practice here?

```
  public function uploadUsingFile($file)
    {
       $rejected = 0;
       $uploaded = 0;

      Excel::load($file, function ($reader) {


        foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row)
        {

            $plateAlreadyExist = Plate::where('serial_number', $row['plate_serial_number'])->exists();

            if ($plateAlreadyExist) {
                $rejected += 1;continue;
            }

            $supplier          = Supplier::firstOrCreate(['name' => $row['supplier_name']]);
            $statusName        = EquipmentStatusCode::firstOrCreate(['name' => $row['status_name']]);
            $plateType         = PlateType::firstOrCreate(['name' => $row['plate_type_name']]);
            $process           = Process::firstOrCreate(['name' => $row['process_name']]);
            $project           = Project::firstOrCreate(['name' => $row['project_name']]);
            $plateQuality      = PlateQuality::firstOrCreate(['name' => $row['plate_quality']]);
            $wafer             = Wafer::firstOrCreate(['serial_number' => $row['wafer_serial_number']]);

            $data = [
                'serial_number'            => $row['plate_serial_number'],
                'crc_code'                 => $row['crc_code'],
                'supplier_id'              => $supplier['id'],
                'equipment_status_code_id' => $statusName['id'],
                'plate_type_id'            => $plateType['id'],
                'process_id'               => $process['id'],
                'project_id'               => $project['id'],
                'plate_quality_id'         => $plateQuality['id'],
                'wafer_id'                 => $wafer['id'],
                'created_by'               => Auth::user()->id,
            ];

            if($data)
            {
              Plate::create($data);
              $uploaded += 1;
            }
          }


      });
return [ 'uploaded' => $uploaded, 'rejected' => $rejected ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a reference to the variables into the closure by using the `use` keyword:

```
...
 Excel::load($file, function ($reader) use(&$rejected, &$uploaded){
...
}
```

[Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous)

Comment: I have tried this method. It's not working for some reason.

Comment: I've updated my answer, did you pass the variables by reference using the `&` operator ?

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. would you care explaining in your answer what `&` has to do with all this?

Comment: You're welcome. Here's a great explanation on passing by reference vs. passing by value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512193/passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value